# Togge CSS class inside a loop in React / TypeScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

Wondering if anyone can help with a small feature I would like to add to a component I'm building.

I have a List component that takes in data passed from DocumentDB as a prop. The List loops through it and spits out a nice looking table with the data and some checkboxes, toggles, etc.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/rBU6H.png

I would like to be able to use the Toggle / Switch component I have (which is basically a fancy styled checkbox) to set or remove an active class on each row. I'm using the status field to set a class on each row, determining if it's active or inactive.

The problem I have is allowing ***multiple*** rows to be active at the same time - so for example Rows 1 and 2 are both off/inactive. If I hit the switch on Row 1 to activate it, then hitting the switch on Row 2 would mark that as active also and not turn off Row 2. I just can't wrap my head around how to hook this up.

Here is some sample data that gets passed over:

```
1: {
    id: "0729aba6-4d35", 
    firstName: "First", 
    lastName: "Last", 
    fullName: "First Last", 
    email: "first@last.com", 
    status: 1, //active
    …
}
```

[This is a stripped down version of the component](https://codepen.io/stckrboy/pen/MvyJPY) (removed fluff that doesn't have any bearing on what I'm doing):

```js
import * as React from 'react';

interface IListProps {
    columns: Array<IColumns>;
    keyString: string,
    listItems: {
        [keyString: string]: any
    };
    selectable?: boolean;
}

export interface IColumns {
    attribute: string;
    displayName?: string | Object;
    sortable?: boolean;
    type: string;
}

interface IListItem {
    active?: boolean;
    selectable?: boolean;
    data: Object;
}

class List extends React.Component<IListProps, any> {

    public render() {

        const items = [];

            for (let key in this.props.listItems) {
                const item  = this.props.listItems[key];
                const listKey = this.props.keyString;

                items.push(
                    <div key={item[listKey]} className={`row -${(item.status && item.status === 1) ? 'active': 'inactive'} -key-${item[listKey]}`}>
                    {
                        <div className={`col -column-checkbox`} key={index}>
                            <Checkbox id={`check-${item[listKey]}`} className="round" />
                        </div>
                        <div className={`col -column-toggle`} key={index}>
                            <Toggle value={`${item.status}`} activeState={item.status} id={`toggle-${item[listKey]}`} name={`toggle-${item[listKey]}`} />
                        </div>
                        <div className={`col -column-toggle`} key={index}>
                            <Avatar small userName={item.userName} />
                            <span className="label">
                                <strong>{item.fullName}</strong>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                    }
                );
            }
            return (
            <div className={'list'} id={'list'}>
                {items}
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default List;
```

If it was just toggling a single row on and off I think I could manage that by passing another prop or something, just can't quite figure out how to independently change the active class on multiple rows inside of the loop.

Comment: Are those circles on the left of the rows checkboxes ? Are you talking about this ? If not and if you're still talking about toggles, how could you toggle multiple of them (as the user I mean) ?

Comment: @SteveChamaillard It's the green switch (I guess that Might be a better way to describe it) on each row. User could turn each row on or off independently by clicking the switch. Toggle does seem a bit off to describe this, I'll maybe update my post to refelect

Comment: Can you modify `Toggle` source code or is it external ?

Comment: I can modify Toggle, it's an internal component I made. Can edit that into the post if required

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So far in this code we can see :

`<List>` which holds `listItems` as a prop. Which means it's read-only.
It's then used to find the class of the row.

You want to change the class of the row when clicking on the `Toggle` component.
That's another way to say you want to change `listItems`.

So you need a method to pass as a prop to `<Toggle>` like so :

```xml
<Toggle onToggle={this.toggle} />
```

Then a method in `<List>` like so :

```typescript
toggle = function (id) {
    return this.props.toggleStatus(id);
}
```

And then in the higher component which holds the state of `listItems`, you can change "for real" the status for the right id.

The idea is to bubble up from the child to the parent the change. The child is only alerting the parent that it's changed. Then the parent becomes the child of its own parent and alerts it too. Etc, until there's no parent anymore since you're at the point where the state lives. And this is where you change it.